# How to send canvas.Children over socket?

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, canvas

I can't serialize it, therefore can't get byte[].

Network whiteboard with .net is impossible?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize what you need to reconstruct it and do so over the other end.

If it isn't marked [serializable] you can't (without lots of effort) do it.